# installing chart manger is failing

Tags: kubernetes-helm

My script is trying to install helm chart manager using below given shell script named "install_helm.sh".

```
echo "Installing servecm (Chart Manager) and common templates to helm3"

helm plugin install https://github.com/jdolitsky/helm-servecm
eval $(helm env |grep HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE)
echo ${HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE}

nohup helm servecm --port=8879 --context-path=/charts --storage local --storage-local-rootdir $HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE/local/ <<EOF &
yes
EOF

CURL_CMD="curl --silent --output /dev/null  http://127.0.0.1:8879/charts"
`${CURL_CMD}`
READY=$?
while [ ${READY} != 0 ]; do
        echo "servecm not yet running. sleeping for 2 seconds"
        sleep 2
        `${CURL_CMD}`
        READY=$?
done
```

however it is not getting installed and giving below error in nohup log file. I could not get why it is not installed. it shows curl issue. but not sure if this is the root cause.
can any one tell me how to debug this?  it used to work some time back on a differnet machine.

```
ChartMuseum not installed. Install latest stable release? (type "yes"): Attempting to install ChartMuseum server (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>AJSFRBH3EY2MFNDJ</RequestId><HostId>xjT8lkHaQIVUlmXOQJTTCGT+3vRA/YfvYwYzdTJM9ppLWUKcbf9qu9c07Ow0dbYDxDTUUSI2yTA=</HostId></Error>)...
Detected your os as "linux"
+ curl -LO 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/chartmuseum/release/<?xml' 'version="1.0"' 'encoding="UTF-8"?>' '<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access' 'Denied</Message><RequestId>AJSFRBH3EY2MFNDJ</RequestId><HostId>xjT8lkHaQIVUlmXOQJTTCGT+3vRA/YfvYwYzdTJM9ppLWUKcbf9qu9c07Ow0dbYDxDTUUSI2yTA=</HostId></Error>/bin/linux/amd64/chartmuseum'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   243    0   243    0     0    250      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   250
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: version="1.0"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: encoding="UTF-8"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: <Error><Code>AccessDenied<
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Denied<
+ rm -rf /tmp/tmp.OzCIXcXSxl
Error: plugin "servecm" exited with error
```

value of env variable HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE

```
root@Ubuntu-20:/home/ravi/ric-dep/bin# helm env |grep HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE
HELM_REPOSITORY_CACHE="/root/.cache/helm/repository"
root@Ubuntu-20:/home/ravi/ric-dep/bin#
```

I get below error while running shell script "install_helm.sh"

```
servecm not yet running. sleeping for 2 seconds
servecm not yet running. sleeping for 2 seconds
servecm not yet running. sleeping for 2 seconds
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the *helm servecm plugin* installer is getting an Access Denied error, similar to this GitHub issue: https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum/issues/328

You can view the error in the second line of the nohup log file content you posted:

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

So the script actually fails quite early, which leads to the succeeding errors in the rest of the script.

A way to troubleshoot these types of things may be to run each command directly in the your terminal instead of in a background script job

Comment: how to fix this?

Comment: How to fix it, I do not know. It is the plugin that fails, so maybe install chartmuseum in a different way than using the installer from https://github.com/jdolitsky/helm-servecm -- 
  


Alternatively you can post an issue at that installers repo to help them out in flagging and fixing it. 
-- 


And to provide a better stopping point for any scripted command when it fails when some error, try starting it with `set -eux` which tells the shell to stop when somethings wrong. 
Explained here: [explainshell set -eux](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=set+-eux)

Comment: Surprising, it was working 1 week back. And I do not see any code changes from that day till today. Which has broken this build. Anyway, I have raised an issue